# Display 5 instead of 20 posts per page on wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I cannot figure out how to display max 5 posts per page on wp-admin table, its showing 20 posts by default, if i put this it shows 5 but pagination doesnt work.

```
function five_posts_per_page( $query ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '5' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post_date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'desc' );
    }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'five_posts_per_page');
```

Pls someone share example?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your post number in wp-admin Dashboard -> Settings - > Reading -> Blog pages show at most . Default number is 10.

Also with code you can have your loop like this :

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : '1';
$args = array (
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'         => '5',
    'post_type'              => 'post',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
       // do stuff
    }

} else {
    // no posts found

}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```